# Public portforwarding with Putty ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, putty

i have alredy tried just like the pic below.

[image: Setting for Putty Tunnel]

now i can use port 8880 with socks5 proxy JUST from Local.

what i want is that i could use PublicIP:8880 with no problem.

the port on PublicIP:8880 is open on the web but its not working on my laptop connected to internet it only works on the server itself as a local.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Windows firewall is blocking the connection, you likely need to add port 8880 to list of allowed ports.

Comment: firewall is off already. but did not work.